# Get file contents from GitHub using Requests and Github API

Tags: python-requests, github-api

I am trying to get the contents of a file from GitHub - using Python Requests and GitHub API. Eventhough the contents look like JSON to me, when I programmatically check, it says it is not JSON format and I am unable to get the JSON data out of it. Here is what I have so far (for a small subset of my URls):

These are the two URLs I have tried and both fail:

```
import requests

from requests.exceptions import HTTPError
from json.decoder import JSONDecodeError

myurl = 'https://github.com/bitpod-io/arsenal/blob/a5af2f9bff13d8b6c6592437a19a712edb49ecb0/tests/utils/samplePolicies.json'
myurl = 'https://github.com/yasuhisa1984/achieve/blob/fa6334c484ee9e7c08e2d280fa16ec5bba5f2369/vendor/bundle/gems/fog-aws-1.2.1/lib/fog/aws/iam/default_policy_versions.json'

token = 'mylongtoken'

    try:
        #response = requests.get(myurl, headers={'Authorization': 'token {}'.format(token), 'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.v3.raw'})
        response = requests.get(myurl, headers={'Authorization': 'token {}'.format(token)})

        response.raise_for_status()
    except HTTPError as http_err:
        print(f'HTTP error occurred: {http_err}')
    except Exception as err:
        print(f'Some other error occurred: {err}')
    else:
        print('Success')
        print(response.headers)
        if 'json' in response.headers.get('Content-Type'):
            try:
                resp_json = response.json()
            except JSONDecodeError:
                print(f'Unable to get data in JSON format.')
            else:
                print(resp_json)
        else:
            print('Response content is not in JSON format.')
```

Can anyone please let me know if I am wrong somewhere. I want to get the file contents as either text or json (preferable) using API.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are downloading from the "raw" content URL, and not the HTML github page. I believe this is the URL for the raw JSON file you want:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yasuhisa1984/achieve/master/vendor/bundle/gems/fog-aws-1.2.1/lib/fog/aws/iam/default_policy_versions.json

The following code works for me with that URL:

```
import requests
url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yasuhisa1984/achieve/master/vendor/bundle/gems/fog-aws-1.2.1/lib/fog/aws/iam/default_policy_versions.json"
resp = requests.get(url)
data = resp.json()
```

Comment: I still get the same error: 'Response content is not in JSON format.' Is my requests.get() properly formulated?

Comment: @user1717931 this is probably to late to help you now but if anyone else faces the same problem, response.content is where to look.

Comment: @AndrewCalder This code still works for me as-is. You shouldn't need to use `response.content` if you are downloading the raw json file.