# How to get raw github data using github API

Tags: github

I want to know how to get this data from the GitHub API.

I know I can get this data as raw but is there any way to get this using GitHub API?

Here is the requested file:

https://github.com/graphql-compose/graphql-compose-examples/blob/master/examples/northwind/data/csv/employees.csv

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66522261/github-limit-on-public-repositories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [seen here](https://gist.github.com/madrobby/9476733#gistcomment-3571788), try

```
curl -GLOf -H "Authorization: token ${GITHUB_TOKEN?not set}" \
-H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v4.raw" \
  "https://api.github.com/repos/$ORG/$REPO/contents/$FILEPATH" -d ref="$REVISION"
```

In your case, for a public repository:

```
curl -GLOf -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v4.raw" \
  "https://api.github.com/repos/graphql-compose/graphql-compose-examples/contents/examples/northwind/data/csv/employees.csv"
```

I just tested it, and got a file `employees.csv` with its raw content in it.

Comment: Is their any api limit for using github API?

Comment: @RishiPurwar Yes there is a "rate limit": https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/rate-limit. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/45427275/6309

Comment: @RishiPurwar As explained in https://github.com/forestgeo/learn/issues/148#issuecomment-439581637, The limit is 60 requests per hour for unauthenticated users (and 5000 for authenticated users). Official documentation: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/resources-in-the-rest-api#rate-limiting